# SQL JOIN multiple ID's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

First Table

```
|product_name   |   category_ids  |
|---------------------------------|
|- apple        |   1, 2          |
|- extra_apple  |   1, 3          |
```

---

Second Table

```
|category_id  |   category_name   |
|---------------------------------|
|- 1          |   fruit           |
|- 2          |   cheap           |  
|- 3          |   expensive       |
```

---

How can I join this, so I get something like this

```
|     product_name  |     category_names   |
--------------------------------------------
|     apple         |     fruit, cheap     |
|     extra_apple   |     fruit, expensive |
```

Comment: The real solution here is to fix your not-normalized table design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it right, add another table:

```
product_categories table
------------------------
product_id
category_id
```

It contains one record for each category a product has.

Answer (score 1):

First table is not Normalize

```
|product_name   |   category_ids  |
|---------------------------------|
|- apple        |   1, 2          |
|- extra_apple  |   1, 3          |
```

First Normalize this Table AS

```
|product_name   |   category_ids  |
|---------------------------------|
|- apple        |   1             |
|- apple        |   2             |
|- extra_apple  |   1             |
|- extra_apple  |   3             |
```

Second Table

```
|category_id  |   category_name   |
|---------------------------------|
|- 1          |   fruit           |
|- 2          |   cheap           |  
|- 3          |   expensive       |
```

MySQL Syntax as: "SELECT T1.product_name, T2.category_name FROM FIRST_TABLE AS T1, SECOND_TABLE AS T2 WHERE T1.category_ids=T2.category_id"

This will give you result as:

```
|     product_name  |     category_names   |
--------------------------------------------
|     apple         |     fruit            |
|     apple         |     cheap            |
|     extra_apple   |     fruit            |
|     extra_apple   |     expensive        |
```